# Ad codes and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, ads

I have a mobile/desktop web site.  My site is built with Bootstrap.  How do I code the mobile only ads to only display on the mobile side, and not on other devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com), and add a `display:none` attribute for ads, on devices that are not mobile.

Comment: within the ad code itself, what exactly would I add and where?

Comment: Typically you add the media queries to the `CSS` file, not into the ad code.

Comment: how do you destination none for mobile ads?

Comment: Why do you mean by `destination none`?